# Oauth: What to do after you get an Access Token

Tags: php, sql, oauth

I have successfully implemented OAuth from a website such that it redirects and returns with an authentication code and access token. However, I am stuck on how to proceed from here. What do I do with the token? How can I check that the user has authenticated when I send the user to different pages on my website?

In a PHP Login system, you could just do:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  /* stuff here */
}
else {
/* redirect here*/
}
```

Do I store the access token of the user in a database on my server? If so, how can I check that the access token is valid and get all the information I want on each page of the website?

Comment: Access tokens are usually used to get private data out of the API.  For example, you request profile information with the access token, the API recognizes the access token and gives you the correct user's information.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that if you got the access token back then you can assume that they have been authenticated on that external system so you can also treat them as a logged in user on your system.

Keep the token in your session for that user and refer to it whenever you need to verify user is logged in.

What other information would you need on each page of your site?

Comment: How do I store the token and access it on other pages along with the scopes that I have defined like Profile, Email etc..?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question... but if you store the token in $_SESSION['token'] = 'token_value' could you not access it in all your pages?

Comment: Sorry for the ill framed question. Yes, i have done that, however i am having trouble accessing the data using that token. How do I request information using that token?

Comment: oh ok... you need to access data from the external provider using that token? That is dependent on how the provider system is setup. They should provide you with explicit guides on how to access their api with the token. It may be just an endpoiint like external-provider(.)com/api/token... Or you may have to use a library like curl to access them. May I ask which provider this is?